# Excel Len function based on condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns in my excel file.

```
   Full ID       Expected Result
  159473A1         159473
  159696A1         159696
  160614A1         160614
  43293J1A          43293
  43293D1A          43293
  43293A2B          43293
  43293J2B          43293
  43293B2B          43293
```

What i had tried :

```
=Left(A2,LEN(A2)-2)

159473
159696
160614
43293J
43293D
43293A
43293J
43293B
53202
```

But has you can see, I cant do that because I still have some characters in the expected results

```
43293J
43293D
43293A
43293J
43293B
```

How can I get my expected results in like the top example?

Comment: Are the last two characters on the right are always to be removed?

Comment: HI @SolarMike Yes always !

Comment: So patently untrue as your 4th example has 3 characters that need removing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `B2` try:

```
=LEFT(A2,MATCH(FALSE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(MID(A2,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A2))),1)*1),),0)-1)
```

If you have access to DA-functions (O365), like `SEQUENCE`:

```
=LEFT(A2,MATCH(FALSE,ISNUMBER(MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1)*1),0)-1)
```

---

[image]

<sup>**Note:** If you are dealing with integers too, maybe to prevent possible errors through `MATCH`, you could use `=LEFT(A2,MATCH(FALSE,ISNUMBER(MID(A2&"A",SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)+1),1)*1),0)-1)`</sup>

Comment: I had apply you formula on the value "95759A1" and returns me a "9"

Comment: @SimonGIS, see my results

Comment: Second solution fix my problem! Awesome Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, very simple in the first instance:

[image]

But you have an issue with line 4... so this will help that:

```
IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A3,LEN(A3)-2))),VALUE(LEFT(A3,LEN(A3)-2)),VALUE(LEFT(A3,LEN(A3)-3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This formula will work for you , remember to click Ctrl+Shift+Enter after pasting formula as its a matrix based formula

mention your email i can send you my workout
    =LEFT(A2,IFERROR(MATCH(1,ISERR(MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1)*1)*1,),)-1)

Comment: I would stay away from volatility when possible.

Comment: you are saying not to use matrix based formulas?

Comment: `INDIRECT` is volatile and therefor will calculate on multiple occasions like opening, saving and changing workbooks, therefor impacting performance significantly when used in larger quantities. Since OP wants to drag the formula I'd suggest to stay away from this. See [this](https://exceljet.net/glossary/volatile-function) for more information and usefull links on the topic.

Comment: That is true, but `INDIRECT` for things like this is a little safer than `ROW` with a direct cell reference.